# jquery - change image according to text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a mysql table with the name of a team in one column (club_name) and an id on another (club_id).
Every team has a logo named with their respective id .png.

Then I have a text input where the user can write the name of a team. There is a jQuery function that shows the possible team names found in the database according to what the user is typing so that it can autocomplete. Once the user selects one of the options the focus moves out of the text input. At this point, I would like the image to change to the logo corresponding to the team. When the text input is empty or the name does not match any team in the database the image should be 0.png

How can I achieve this? My code so far is below:

EDIT:

I have three problems right now:

1. The method suggested to store the club id in the json object is only
   returning the first row of the table.

The method is below (although it only returns one row of the table it does work, the image changes to the appropriate one - I ran a little test by replacing 'thisclub' with the name of the club):

```
<script>
var clublist = [ 
<?php
$search_clubs = " SELECT club_id, club_name FROM clubs ORDER BY club_id DESC";
$result_clubs = mysql_query($search_clubs);
echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($result_clubs)); //only returns one row
?>
];
</script>
```

Using another method I was able to have all the rows in the json object but this one did not work when I ran the same test by replacing 'thisclub' with the name of one club):

```
<script>
var clublist = [ 
<?php
$clubid = array(); $clubname = array();
 $search_clubs = mysql_query(" SELECT club_id, club_name FROM clubs ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($search_clubs)) {
$clubid[] = $row["club_id"]; // or smth like $row["video_title"] for title
$clubname[] = $row["club_name"];
}
$res = array($clubid, $clubname);
echo json_encode($res);
?>
];
</script>
```

2. The second problem is I don't know what to replace 'thisclub' with.
   In other words, how to get the value returned by the function.
3. I am now using two vars - one to store the name of the clubs only, for the original function, the other one for the name of the clubs and respective id, for the function that makes the image change. This is because I don't know what changes to make in the original function so that it searches for the names in the new var (which contains club_id too)

The full code is below.

```
<img id="team-logo" src="logos/0.png"/>

<input type="text" class="club-name" name="home" autocomplete="off"/>

<script>
var clubs = [ 
    <?php
    $search_clubs = " SELECT club_name FROM clubs ";
    $result_clubs = mysql_query($search_clubs);
    while($clubs = mysql_fetch_array($result_clubs)) {
        $club_name = $clubs['club_name'];
        echo '"'.$club_name.'",';
    }
    ?>
];

var clublist = [ 
<?php
$search_clubs = " SELECT club_id, club_name FROM clubs ORDER BY club_id DESC";
$result_clubs = mysql_query($search_clubs);
echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($result_clubs)); //only returns one row
?>
];

$(".club-name").autocomplete({
    source: clubs,
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 0,
    close: function(event, ui){
        if (!event.keyCode || event.keyCode === 13){
            $(this).parents('form').find('.club-name').filter(function (){
                return $(this).val() === '';
            }).first().focus();
            //
        }

        clubid = "";
        $.each(clublist, function (i, elem) {
            if (elem.club_name === thisclub) {
                clubid = elem.club_id;
                $("#team-logo").attr("src", clubid+".png");
            }
        });
        if(clubid == "") {
            // show default image
            $("#team-logo").attr("src", "0.png");
        }
        //$("#team-logo").attr("src", clubs+".png");
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get the club_id from the original SELECT that you do.

Then on the focus out you can do something along the lines of:

```
$("#team-logo").attr("src", club_id+".png");
```

And that will set the image src to the new image.

Edit:

To expand a bit, storing the results of the sql query in a json object using json_encode() would allow you to use something like:

```
<script>
    var clublist = [ 
    <?php
    $search_clubs = " SELECT club_id, club_name FROM clubs ";
    $result_clubs = mysql_query($search_clubs);
    echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_array($result_clubs));
    ?>
    ];
</script>

// Run the following code inside the focus.out section and set thisclub to the returned clubname

clubid = "";
$.each(clublist, function (i, elem) {
    if (elem.club_name === thisclub) {
        clubid = elem.club_id;
        $("#team-logo").attr("src", clubid+".png");
    }
});
if(clubid == "") {
    // show default image
    $("#team-logo").attr("src", "0.png");
}
```

Second Edit (Complete working example):

I've tested the following and I believe it includes everything you're looking for. The problem seemed to be in the formatting of the php array when passed to json encode. Pay close attention to the HTML changes.

```
$sql = " SELECT club_id, club_name FROM clubs ORDER BY club_id DESC";

$result_clubs = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result_clubs) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$clubs = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_clubs)){
    $clubs[] = array('club_id' => $row['club_id'], 'club_name' => $row['club_name']);
}
?>

<img id="team-logo" src="logos/0.png"/>

<input id="clubname" type="text" class="club-name" name="home" autocomplete="off"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var clubs = [ 
    <?php
    foreach($clubs as $club) {
        $club_name = $club['club_name'];
        echo '"'.$club_name.'",';
    }
    ?>
];    

var clublist =  <?php echo json_encode($clubs)?>;  //only returns one row

$(".club-name").autocomplete({
    source: clubs,
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 0,
    close: function(event, ui){
        if (!event.keyCode || event.keyCode === 13){
            $(this).parents('form').find('.club-name').filter(function (){
                return $(this).val() === '';
            }).first().focus();
            //
        }
        clubid = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < clublist.length; i++) {
            obj = clublist[i];
            if(obj.club_name == $("#clubname").val()){
                clubid = obj.club_id;
                $("#team-logo").attr("src", clubid+".png");
            } 
        }
        if(clubid == "") {
            // show default image
            $("#team-logo").attr("src", "0.png");
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to make the image change on focus out by adding the line of code you wrote but how can I store the club_id in the array and then get it in your line to display that image.

EDIT: Also, when empty (let's say the user deletes what he had written) or not matching any team it should go back to 0.png

Comment: No problem @HenriqueA. I've edited my answer. Let me know if that doesn't get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I am sorry @Optimus , it seems pretty easy from your suggestion but I am not very experienced, have been trying in the last 25 minutes and can't get it done. how do I store the results with json_encode() ? simply create an associative array with club_id and club_name and then use json_encode($array) ? and then how does the jQuery function you wrote call that json object?

Comment: You're exactly right @HenriqueA. You create the array using `var ar = <?php echo json_encode($array) ?>;` Then you can call the elements of the array using ar.clubname and ar.clubid. Replace jsonobj in the foreach (`$.each`) above.

Comment: If this solved your problem, @HenriqueA., kindly accept the answer. Otherwise, I'd happy to keep advising.

Comment: It didn't @Optimus. I have been trying to solve it myself so I don't have to ask easy things but the fact is I can't. I will edit my original post. And thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks @HenriqueA. I've added a complete, working example. I left out the connection details, because you seem to have that working. Let me know if that doesn't solve your issue.